# Laptop extended monitor second desktop only not working

Tags: windows, hdmi, vga, extended-desktop

`OS - Windows 10 64bits
Laptop - Dell
LCD monitor - Samsung
Cables - HDMI to VGA adapter`

**second desktop only not working** - Both Lcd monitor and laptop black, sound no problem and lcd monitor led light is on.

**Note** - Duplicate screen and extended work fine only second desktop only not working. Before this everything is working, this happen suddenly

**Tests** - Tested on another Samsung monitor and TV with same HDMI to VGA adapter it works prefect. So i guess it is my Samsung LCD monitor problem

Any idea how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I manage to make "second screen only" works but something goes wrong.

First i have to turn monitor plug off and unplug hdmi to vga cable then switch my laptop win + p to "second screen only" then follow by plugin hdmi cable and turn on monitor plug on and now it works.  It not work if I turn on the monitor first and connect hdmi second. If my screen sleep after mins or I switch to another mode and come back to "second screen only" then problem comes again.

**Update 2**
I tested my laptop with same cable on another same model Samsung monitor and it works perfect. The only different is when I connect to the "problem" monitor it automatic pick up "Extend" mode and the other monitor it pick up "PC screen only" mode at first. So is my laptop keep some hdmi memory?  anyway to clear the memory in windows?

Comment: Sometimes displays do not handle adapters well, depending on the type. I have seen it a few times. Are you trying the same cable on the same type of display, but a different unit?

Comment: yes, same cable different devices because I got only 1 HDMI to VGA. I found another thing. Please check my updates, see if u got any hints.

Comment: If you are going from HDMI to VGA, the computer might not like that as it is not getting a HDCP handshake.

Comment: What do you mean by "might not like that" ?  @MrStatic

Comment: If for some reason HDCP is required, that isn't possible with a HDMI->VGA adapter. So it won't allow the screen to work. Also as @Dupree3 has pointed out adapters like this don't always work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

Delete the **Connectivity** and **Configuration** under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers in registry

**Remember to back up both key before  deleted.**

For more detail pls check [here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN137488/EN)

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the display driver and re-enable it.

It's as simple as that.

(Of course, you should have your drivers updated.)